# python selenium wait for page to load

Tags: python, selenium

I've written a script that gets data from a page, but sometimes the page takes time to load and so when it pull the html into a soup object sometimes It pulls nothing as the page still needs to finish.

I wrote the following code for waiting the page to finish.

```
def scrape_page(url):
     browser.get(url)    
     try:
        WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(browser.find_element_by_id ("selection-box")))
        #Extract Source Code 
        html = browser.page_source;
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
```

It works

But I'm getting the following error when I call the function;

```
TypeError: find_element() argument after * must be a sequence, not WebElement
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think you should use `presence_of_element_located` like this:

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "myDynamicElement"))
    )
```

as described in the [manual](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html).

Comment: I tried this originallly, , but get the error global name By is not defined. Only thing that is different is that Im using Chrome Driver instead of firefox

Comment: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html?highlight=#module-selenium.webdriver.common.by

Comment: @GrantMcKinnonG import `By` before use it: `from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By`

Comment: @GrantMcKinnon- You have to import as    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

Comment: The link in this answer has died.  RIP link.

Answer (score 4):

After 6 years from this question, all the solutions I looked for was not good for my situation, I found the solution in other programming language and I did implementation for Python, so this is the best way to wait a page to fully load.

```
WebDriverWait(self.driver, self.SERVER_TIMEOUT).until(
        lambda wd: self.driver.execute_script("return document.readyState") == 'complete',
        "Page taking too long to load"
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

I apply this func to every WebElement I need to use.

```
from selenium import webdriver

def FindElem(Driver: webdriver, XPath: str, Timeout: int = 300):
    while Timeout > 0:
        try:
            return Driver.find_element_by_xpath(XPath)
        except: # if element isn't already loaded or doesn't exist
            time.sleep(1)
            Timeout -= 1
    raise RuntimeError(f"Page loading timeout") # or whatever the hell you want
```

Usage:

```
Driver = webdriver.Firefox()
webdriver.get("http://somewhere.com/somepage.html")
MyWebElement = FindElem(Driver, "//input[@name='email']") # raise exception if timeout
```